# What determines the number of electors in each state of the US

Tags: united-states, election, electoral-college

I would like to know what determines the number of electors in each state of the US for presidential election. I have read that "Every State is allocated a number of votes equal to the number of senators and representatives in its U.S. Congressional delegation" [here](https://www.archives.gov/electoral-college/allocation)

So then the question is: what determines this new number ? Is it only based on demography ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Mostly the (Decennial) Census

Generally, the electoral formula is Electoral Votes = Representatives + Senators.  Each state has two Senators, so that's 100 of the 538 total Electoral Votes.

Washington DC gets three electors; while they technically have [shadow congresspeople](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_congressperson#:%7E:text=The%20current%20shadow%20United%20States,Paul%20Strauss%20and%20Mike%20Brown.), those don't get to vote in the House or Senate.  In keeping with historical values of ["No Taxation Without Representation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_taxation_without_representation), they receive electors so they have some measure of representation.  100 Senators + 3 DC Electors = 103 so far

Every ten years, the US conducts its [census](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/decennial-census/decade.html) to determine, among other things, the population of each state.  Each state receives Representatives proportional to its fraction of the total US population, with a minimum of one representative per state and a total of 435.

- For example, California had a population of 37.37 million in 2010 out of a total US population of 309.3 million.

  37.37e6 (CA pop) / 309.3e6 (US pop) = x (CA Reps) / 435 (US Reps).  Solving for x rounds to 53 seats, which is the current number of California Representatives in the House.

435 Representatives + 100 Senators + 3 DC Electors = 538 Electoral Votes

Though this is slightly outside the scope of your question, this is part of the reason the census has [recently been politicized](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/08/04/us/2020-census-ending-early.html): an undercount in (often specific) urban areas would lead to lesser representation in traditionally blue areas, giving Republicans greater proportional representation.

Comment: In addition to its shadow representative, the district has actual official representation in the house in the form of a nonvoting delegate.